# Is MySQL using up all the memory?

Tags: memory-usage, mariadb, mysql5.5

I need help with reading this output of `free -m`. This server has a total of 32 GB of ram but it shows `9383` used and `290` free. The rest seems to be in the `buff/cache`. I am running mysql on this server and we get high CPU usage from time to time intermittently. I was wondering if this had to do with all the memory being used up and it's swapping or possibly a MySQL configuration issue?

Does buff/cache mean the 22GB of RAM is free or used up? Only thing running on this server is MySQL and we do get tons of queries a day. Approximately 6 million queries per hour.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31876        9383         290         216       22203       21840
Swap:         16383        1541       14842
```

Comment: This is entirely normal you will have to look elsewhere for your solution.

Answer (score -2):

On your server, 22203 MB of memory are used for caching purpose (ie: they are not in use by any application). As buffer/cache memory can be reclamed immediately, it should be treated as "free" memory. For this reason, watch the "available" column: it shows 21840, which is perfectly in-line with your real memory consumption.

Comment: The linked duplicate and all of it's related Q&A fully explain this.Please use your close->duplicate vote rather then writing your own answer.